# Link my profile employer to company page on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

The company I work in doesn't appear in the list that pops down when I type in the box "What's your employer?", but it does have a Facebook Page.

I want to "link" the page to my profile info, so when they click the company name on my profile ("Developer at ***_*_**"), they arrive at the company page.

There are some tutorials around (e.g. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/link-employers-facebook-details-facebook-page/) that propose a workaround to this. However, the page code seems to have changed since this tutorial was written, and also it (apparently) requires a numeric page ID, and the page I want to link to has a vanity URL. There are also some methods to find the actual page ID by looking at image addresses and etc., but these also seem to have changed, since I can't really find the ID anywhere.

So, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by finding a way to find (!!) the actual ID of the page. It mostly involved searching the page code for ".php?id=" and filtering out manually the links to other profiles.

Then the above method should work fine. I didn't want to install an extension just for this, though, so I made a little javascript snippet that makes the relevant fields visible. You click "Edit" in the position you want to link, paste the following code in the address bar, press enter and proceed with the tutorial in posted in the original question:

```
javascript:for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("employer_id").length; i++) { document.getElementsByName("employer_id")[i].type = "text"; } return false;
```

Comment: Nice solution, I have had this problem for linking other fields in the info section.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have already *"liked"* the page you wan't to link to. 
it should work after that..it works for me. but I am a page administrator...so...that might also have something to do with it

Comment: I had tried that, didn't work though =/

Comment: I think this worked for me. I'm not a page admin.